# Efficiency of each_char vs. getc (and analagous methods) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io

How do the iterator methods such as `each_char`, `each_line`. etc. compare to while-looped`getc`,`gets`, etc. methods for reading large files? Mainly, what is the overhead for using each method, which one will use more memory, and which one will be faster?

Essentially, which will be better in terms of memory, overhead, and speed if `file` is a 100MB text file?

```
file.each_char{
|ch|
    #process ch
}
```

vs

```
ch = ""
until(file.eof?)
    ch = file.getc
    #process ch
end
```

Or is there an even better method of doing this?

Comment: Why don't you test them?

Comment: @EdS. I can easily test for speed. But I'm really much more interested in the overhead that Ruby uses to perform these operations.

Comment: So overhead in terms of memory?  You can test that too.

Comment: @EdS. Well then care to suggest a method of easily doing that?

Comment: You could start by using a [Ruby memory profiler](https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ruby+memory+profiler)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily answer questions like this definitively using the [Ruby Standard Library's *benchmark*](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html) package.

> Or is there an even better method of doing this?

I think so. While a C program might reasonably process a file one character at a time, Ruby has a towering edifice of String and Array functionality built-in, and that's all written in C so it runs quickly.

It may not seem efficient to split a line into words and then just use a few, or just count them, or whatever, but it's probably a lot faster than parsing that line one character at a time and it's more easily read and rewritten if necessary.

In general, I would suggest that a Ruby program leverage the library and do as much as possible working with objects that are as abstract as possible.

Comment: You can easily check the speed of what is going on with the benchmark library, just like you can just as easily do this using the Unix `time` command. I'm more interested in the overhead that Ruby is using to perform these operations in terms of memory and object creation.